# Residues of the product of the gamma and zeta functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

If we have a function of the form $f(z)=\Gamma(z)\zeta(z)$ where $\Gamma(z)$ is the standard gamma function, and $\zeta(z)$ is the Riemann zeta function, then how would we calculate the residues?

I know that the Riemann zeta function has a pole at $z=1$ with a residue of 1, and that the gamma function has residues, at the poles $z=-n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, given by
$$\text{Res}_{z=-n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!},$$
but how would we find the residues of the product of the function?

Comment: If $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$, and $g$ is holomorphic there, what is the residue of $f\cdot g$ at $z_0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahh, the residue of $f\cdot g$ would be just the residue of $f$ ... correct?

Comment: Not quite. What is the residue of $c\cdot f$ when $c$ is a constant? Can you generalise?

Comment: I'm unsure what to do ...

Comment: Take a simple example. Say $f(z) = 1/z$. What is the residue of $g(z)/z$ at $0$?

Comment: I'm unsure what the residue would be in the general case for $g(z)/z)$ at $0$.

Comment: What **is** the residue of a function at a point?

Comment: The coefficient of the $1/z$ term in the Laurent expansion ... I think I may be blanking on something obvious here ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can always determine the residue of a product by multiplying the Laurent expansions of the factors. Generally, that is tedious (and doesn't lead to a closed form expression), but in the case where one of the factors has a simple pole, and the other factor is holomorphic at the point in question, the situation is quite simple: If

\begin{align}
f(z) &= \sum_{n = -1}^{+\infty} a_n \cdot (z-z_0)^n,\\
g(z) &= \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} b_k\cdot (z-z_0)^k,
\end{align}

then it is easy to see that the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ in the product is $a_{-1}\cdot b_0$.

Thus in this case, we have the simple

$$\operatorname{Res} (f\cdot g; z_0) = g(z_0) \cdot \operatorname{Res}(f; z_0).\tag{$\ast$}$$

For the product of the $\Gamma$-function and the Riemann $\zeta$-function, we are always in that situation. All poles of either factor are simple, and the two functions have no common pole. So $\operatorname{Res} (\Gamma\cdot \zeta; 1) = \Gamma(1)\cdot \operatorname{Res}(\zeta;1) = 1\cdot 1 = 1$, and for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (where we use the convention $0\in \mathbb{N}$), $\Gamma$ has a simple pole at $-n$, and we find

$$\operatorname{Res}(\Gamma\cdot\zeta; -n) = \zeta(-n)\operatorname{Res}(\Gamma; -n).$$